# how to assign generic refernce to a method which is giving non generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics

How do I assign a generic reference to the return value of method which returns a non-generic `ArrayList`? I don't know what type of `ArrayList` it is returning.

For example, I have some old class:

```
class Employee {
    ArrayList al;

    public ArrayList getEmplist() {
        return al;
    }    
}
```

I am calling this method from:

```
class UseEmp {
    ??? = getEmplist();
}
```

How can I handle this, can I use object or anything?

Comment: Try: `List<?> = getEmplist()`.

Comment: ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<Employee>(). it is generic list of Employee object

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyObj> l = (List<MyObj>) getEmplist();
```

You will get a warning which you can suppress in an annotation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301050/warnings-in-java-when-casting-to-a-generic-type) about how to suppress the warnings.